# Liquify images like photoshop with python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I've been trying to liquify/warp images randomly with pil, opencv and scikit, but it's becoming unclear to me how to approach to this

[Source image randomly generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVGvu.png)

[Example of desired result made with photoshop (not the same file, generated another source, hope it's still clear)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRB3L.png)

From my understandings, to warp an image, you create a grid of coordinates, and move around this coordinates, implementing also something like interpolation (if I'm not wrong)

I've been trying this 2 methods

1. Method 1

```
    import np
    from skimage import transform
    #linesB PIL.Image, PNG, filled with random geometric figures
    poi = np.array([[0,0]])
    projection = np.array([[0,0]])
    sections = 20
    w, h = linesB.size
    for i in range(w//sections, w, w//sections):
        for j in range(h//sections, h, h//sections):
            poi = np.concatenate(( poi, np.array([[i, j]]) ))
            #random move a point somewhere
            offx, offy = [random.randint(-900, 900) for i in range(2)]
            projection = np.concatenate(( projection, np.array([[i - offx, j - offy]]) ))
    
    
    linesB = np.array(linesB)
    tform = transform.estimate_transform('projective', poi, projection)
    linesB = transform.warp(linesB, tform.inverse, mode = 'symmetric')
    linesB = Image.fromarray((linesB * 255).astype(np.uint8))
```

[But the results has nothing to do with warping, it's just a perspective changer script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScRi2.png)
I was thinking to move around points and that scikit could so something about the interpolation, but clearly I'm wrong

2. Method 2

```
    #linesB still a PIL.Image
    linesB = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(linesB), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    rows, cols, _ = linesB.shape
    linesB2 = np.zeros(linesB.shape, dtype = linesB.dtype)

    offx, offy = [random.uniform(1.0, 590.0) for i in range(2)]
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            offset_x = int(offx * math.cos(i*math.pi/offx))
            offset_y = int(offy * math.sin(j*math.pi/offy))
            #offset_x = int(random.uniform(20.0, 90.0) * math.sin(2 * 3.14 * i / 150))
            #offset_y = int(random.uniform(20.0, 90.0) * math.cos(2 * 3.14 * j / 150))
            if i+offset_y < rows and j+offset_x < cols:
                linesB2[i,j] = linesB[(i+offset_y)%rows,(j+offset_x)%cols]
            else:
                linesB2[i,j] = 0
```

With this method, the warping is not very different one from each other, and everything is very wavy, also, it's liquifying the borders meaning there will be transparent or black sections

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2UwO.png)

The third method I've not yet written, would consist in the PIL transform method, but at this point I'm not even sure I'm in the right direction. That would consist of something called "mash", but I still have to make researches

Anyone could help?

Comment: See skimage transform piecewiseaffine at https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.PiecewiseAffineTransform